# IIS7 Applications: Deny WAN visitors and allow LAN visitors

Tags: security, iis-7, permissions

Consider an IIS7 deployment with multiple Applications under a Web Site. Each is running under its own AppPool. We want to disallow all outside visitors access to one Application in particular. All internal users should be allowed access.

The current strategy is to check the requesting IP address. This likely could be done in IIS7 and a web.config. The screenshot is the first stab at allowing internal users. Those who present from:

- `192.168.0.X` should be **allowed**.
- an external IP, (i.e. a public address) should be **denied**.

  [image: First stab at IIS7 settings]

**Question:** How would you configure your Application to suit this requirement, either by:

- `inetmgr` or
- `web.config`

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Using inetmgr you would do exactly what you have done. And all inetmgr does is write this in to your web.config file...

Comment: You're already doing it correctly. What else do you need, exactly?

Comment: Thanks everyone; I need to determine how to block outside addresses. I think I've figured out the 'allow inside visitors' rule, but the deny is still the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the IIS Manager and deny all access except from your private IP subnet.

That or host the site on a second different IP and setup internal DNS to handle the name lookup, and not make the app available from the outside at all.

Comment: +1 Seems simple enough... I'd use an ISA/TMG or some other good publishing firewall for this though.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are asking as I am having the same issue. To try and describe this another way, I want to restrict access to "one" of the Applications on my Site, to a specific list of IP addresses and ranges.  However, when you configure this in InetMgr, the restriction is placed on the Site, not the specific Application.  I also tried adding the IP address restriction rules manually to my web.config in the Application and that did not work either.

How do you add an IP address restriction to the Application and leave the rest of the Site open?